# C difference between main thread and other threads

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, setjmp

Is there a difference between the first thread and other threads created during runtime. Because I have a program where to abort longjmp is used and a thread should be able to terminate the program (exit or abort don't work in my case). Could I safely use pthread_kill_other_threads_np and then longjmp?

Comment: `longjmp`? In 2021? Whatever is going on here? This sounds like an XY Problem. What's the actual issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: Nothing wrong with `longjmp`, but indeed it sounds like an XY problem

Comment: `exit` will exit all threads, terminating the program.  Why won't it work in your case?  Do some of the threads need cleanup before they can exit?

Comment: The 'main thread' is created by the OS process loader, rather than your app code.  Apart from that, no, they are all just threads:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what platform you're talking about, but `pthread_kill_other_threads_np` is not a standard function and not a remotely reasonable operation anymore than `free_all_malloced_memory` would be. Process termination inherently involves the termination of all threads atomically with respect to each other (they don't see each other terminate).

As for `longjmp`, while there is nothing wrong with `longjmp`, you cannot use it to jump to a context in a different thread.

It sounds like you have an XY problem here; you've asked about whether you can use (or how to use) particular tools that are not the right tool for whatever it is you want, without actually explaining what your constraints are.